# Thymeleaf iterate map of maps to create table with rowspans

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, freemarker, spring-thymeleaf

Assuming I have

```
Date occuranceDate; //Dates only have years, months, days 
String eventOwner;
String eventData;
```

Sample Data:

```
12-01-2021 , John Doe, random event data 1
12-01-2021, Jane Doe, random event data 2
12-01-2021, Jane Doe, random event data 3
12-02-2021, John Doe, random event data 4
```

I am trying to create a table with thymeleaf that would have three columns `Event Date, Event Owner, event Data`. Such that

1. event date would have row span of size equals to the number of event Data on that date.
2. event owner would have a row span of size equals to the number of event data on that date for that event owner
3. event data

For the data above, the table would like

[image]

I want to create a table that would display the list of `eventData`, grouped by the `eventOwner`, grouped by the `occuranceDate`

I am passing `Map<Date, Map<String, List<String>>>` to Thymeleaf (I am open to change data structure). I would appreciate any help in how to generate the table , it is proving to be very complicated.

I tried following : [Thymeleaf Table issues with rowspan (1 Order, N Articles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999679/thymeleaf-table-issues-with-rowspan-1-order-n-articles) but that becomes complicated with three different columns that are representing nested maps and lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just a `List<Event>`.  (I did add a variable `occuranceDateString` which is just a string version of `occuranceDate`.)

```html
<table>
  <tr   th:each="event, stat: ${events}"
        th:with="
          newDate=${(stat.index == 0) || (events[stat.index - 1].occuranceDateString != event.occuranceDateString)},
          newOwner=${newDate || (stat.index == 0) || (events[stat.index - 1].eventOwner != event.eventOwner)},
        " valign="top">
    <td th:if="${newDate}" th:text="${event.occuranceDateString}" th:rowspan="${events.?[occuranceDateString == #root.event.occuranceDateString].size()}" />
    <td th:if="${newOwner}" th:text="${event.eventOwner}" th:rowspan="${events.?[occuranceDateString == #root.event.occuranceDateString].?[eventOwner == #root.event.eventOwner].size()}" />
    <td th:text="${event.eventData}" />
  </tr>      
</table>
```

Comment: I added a small bug fix... `newOwner=${(stat.index == 0)...` was changed to `newOwner=${newDate || (stat.index == 0)...` (if a new date started with the same owner as the last row)